# Redirecting content of man mkdir to two files in linux

Tags: linux, redirect

why does manual has no content ? after executing:

```
man mkdir > manual > manualbis
```

i was expecting that manual will have the content filled with the manual of mkdir command and not left empty as the redirection will change the standard output from screen to file manuel and after that the content of manuel will be copied to manualbis, is this correct ??

Comment: That is not correct.  There is no copy.  The shell redirects stdout to the file manual, truncating manual (discarding any data that it may have had).  Then it redirects stdout to `manualbis`, then it runs the command and all of its output goes to `manualbis`.

Comment: `zsh` will do what you want with that syntax, btw. https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A command can only redirect output to one file or pipe, not multiple files.

Use `tee` to write to a file in addition to writing to stdout.

```
man mkdir | tee manual > manualbis
```